I am trying to derive the E-L equations from this paper but do not get the same as the authors. please help!
I am trying to follow the paper "Neutron Star constraints on the H dibaryon" Glendenning
$L_D=D^*_\mu H^* D^\mu H -m^*_H H^* H$
This is the lagrangian given. Here $D_\mu = \partial_\mu+ i g_{\omega} V_\mu$ and $m^*_H= m_H -g_\sigma \sigma$.
When I derive the E-L equations I get
$$D_\mu D^\mu H-m^*_H H=0.$$
But Glendenning gets $$[D^*_\mu D^\mu +m_H^*]H(\omega,\vec{k})=0.$$
I cant see how these are equivalent. I also don't know how the energy contribution is $\varepsilon_H= m_H^* \rho_H$ or for an s-wave the momentum is zero so $\omega_H=m^*_H+g_\omega V_0$

Do you  mean $D_\mu = \partial_\mu+ig V_\mu$?  I.e is there a missing plus (or minus) sign?

doi.

Take zero coupling and recheck your EL equation.
